# UWP Calculator Difficulty

Tags: c#, uwp

I have this calculator that i have done, it is almost complete but it has a problem that i cannot find.
For some reason it doesn't reset when i want it to and i cannot make many calculations after eachother so example : 3+5+9*1-4 etc. The first 2 will work but the rest won't work at all.

What is wrong with my UWP application?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace Calc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        string input = string.Empty;
        string x = string.Empty;
        string y = string.Empty;
        char operation;
        double result = 0.0;


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox.Text = "";
            input += "1";
            this.textBox.Text += input;

        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox.Text = " ";
            input += "2";
            this.textBox.Text += input;
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox.Text = " ";
            input += "3";
            this.textBox.Text += input;
        }

        private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox.Text = " ";
            input += "4";
            this.textBox.Text += input;
        }

        private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox.Text = " ";
            input += "5";
            this.textBox.Text += input;
        }

        private void Button_Click_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox.Text = " ";
            input += "6";
            this.textBox.Text += input;

        }

        private void Button_Click_6(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox.Text = " ";
            input += "7";
            this.textBox.Text += input;
        }

        private void Button_Click_7(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox.Text = " ";
            input += "8";
            this.textBox.Text += input;
        }

        private void Button_Click_8(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox.Text = " ";
            input += "9";
            this.textBox.Text += input;
        }

        private void Button_Click_9(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Marucs
            this.textBox.Text = " ";
            input += "42";
            this.textBox.Text += input;
        }

        private void Button_Click_10(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //0
            this.textBox.Text = " ";
            input += "0";
            this.textBox.Text += input;
        }

        private void Button_Click_11(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //F = m*a
        }

        private void Button_ClickPlus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            x = input;
            operation = '+';
            input = string.Empty;
        }

        private void Button_ClickMinus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            x = input;
            operation = '-';
            input = string.Empty;
        }

        private void Button_ClickTimes(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            x = input;
            operation = '*';
            input = string.Empty;
        }

        private void Button_ClickDEv(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            x = input;
            operation = '/';
            input = string.Empty;
        }

        private void Button_ClickEqual(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            y = input;
            double num1, num2;

            double.TryParse(x, out num1);
            double.TryParse(y, out num2);

            if (operation == '+')
            {
                result = num1 + num2;
                textBox.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '-')
            {
                result = num1 - num2;
                textBox.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '*')
            {
                result = num1 * num2;
                textBox.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '/')
            {
                if (num2 != 0)
                {
                    result = num1 / num2;
                    textBox.Text = result.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox.Text = "DIV/Zero!";
                }

            }
        }

        private void Button_ClickReset(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

```
#pragma checksum "C:\Users\karwa\Desktop\Program 2\1\Calc\MainPage.xaml" "{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}" "8D9E2B39F9566766D5661DBF03A2A9C7"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Calc
{
    partial class MainPage : 
        global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page, 
        global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector,
        global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Connect()
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks"," 10.0.18362.1")]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        public void Connect(int connectionId, object target)
        {
            switch(connectionId)
            {
            case 2: // MainPage.xaml line 12
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element2 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element2).Click += this.Button_Click;
                }
                break;
            case 3: // MainPage.xaml line 13
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element3 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element3).Click += this.Button_Click_1;
                }
                break;
            case 4: // MainPage.xaml line 14
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element4 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element4).Click += this.Button_Click_2;
                }
                break;
            case 5: // MainPage.xaml line 15
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element5 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element5).Click += this.Button_Click_3;
                }
                break;
            case 6: // MainPage.xaml line 16
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element6 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element6).Click += this.Button_Click_4;
                }
                break;
            case 7: // MainPage.xaml line 17
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element7 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element7).Click += this.Button_Click_5;
                }
                break;
            case 8: // MainPage.xaml line 18
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element8 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element8).Click += this.Button_Click_6;
                }
                break;
            case 9: // MainPage.xaml line 19
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element9 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element9).Click += this.Button_Click_7;
                }
                break;
            case 10: // MainPage.xaml line 20
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element10 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element10).Click += this.Button_Click_8;
                }
                break;
            case 11: // MainPage.xaml line 21
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element11 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element11).Click += this.Button_Click_10;
                }
                break;
            case 12: // MainPage.xaml line 22
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element12 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element12).Click += this.Button_Click_9;
                }
                break;
            case 13: // MainPage.xaml line 23
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element13 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element13).Click += this.Button_Click_11;
                }
                break;
            case 14: // MainPage.xaml line 24
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element14 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element14).Click += this.Button_ClickPlus;
                }
                break;
            case 15: // MainPage.xaml line 25
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element15 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element15).Click += this.Button_ClickMinus;
                }
                break;
            case 16: // MainPage.xaml line 26
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element16 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element16).Click += this.Button_ClickTimes;
                }
                break;
            case 17: // MainPage.xaml line 27
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element17 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element17).Click += this.Button_ClickDEv;
                }
                break;
            case 18: // MainPage.xaml line 28
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element18 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element18).Click += this.Button_ClickEqual;
                }
                break;
            case 19: // MainPage.xaml line 30
                {
                    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button element19 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)(target);
                    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button)element19).Click += this.Button_ClickReset;
                }
                break;
            case 20: // MainPage.xaml line 31
                {
                    this.textBox = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox)(target);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            this._contentLoaded = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// GetBindingConnector(int connectionId, object target)
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks"," 10.0.18362.1")]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        public global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector GetBindingConnector(int connectionId, object target)
        {
            global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector returnValue = null;
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Page
    x:Class="Calc.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Calc"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="1142" Height="1289">

    <Grid Margin="0,0,10,10">
        <Button Content="1" Margin="113,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="165" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="2" Margin="337,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="166" FontSize="48" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="3" Margin="553,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="166" FontSize="48" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
        <Button Content="4" Margin="113,400,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="165" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_3"/>
        <Button Content="5" Margin="337,404,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="166" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_4"/>
        <Button Content="6" Margin="553,404,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="166" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_5"/>
        <Button Content="7" Margin="113,518,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="165" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_6"/>
        <Button Content="8" Margin="337,518,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="166" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_7"/>
        <Button Content="9" Margin="553,518,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="166" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_8"/>
        <Button Content="0" Margin="337,631,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="166" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_10"/>
        <Button Content="Marcus" Margin="113,631,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="165" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_9"/>
        <Button Content="F=M*A" Margin="553,631,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="166" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_Click_11"/>
        <Button Content="+" Margin="781,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="165" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_ClickPlus"/>
        <Button Content="-" Margin="781,404,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="165" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_ClickMinus"/>
        <Button Content="*" Margin="781,518,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="165" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_ClickTimes"/>
        <Button Content="/" Margin="781,631,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="165" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_ClickDEv"/>
        <Button Content="=" Margin="113,740,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="606" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_ClickEqual"/>

        <Button Content="Reset" Margin="781,740,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="165" FontSize="48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,2.202" Click="Button_ClickReset"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="113,63,0,0" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="190" Width="833" FontSize="72"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the rest button does not work is that you don’t set “input” to empty after each reset.

For continuous calculations, such as 3+5+9*1-4, you can use [DataTable.Compute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=net-5.0) method, which computes the given expression on the current rows that pass the filter criteria.

```
string str = "3+5+9*1-4";
object result = new DataTable().Compute(str, null); //The value of result is 13
```

So the point is the creation of string expression. When clicking the button that content is number or symbol , you can append character to the string expression.

As follows:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        textBox.Text +="1";
    }
……

    private void Button_Click_10(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Text += "0";
    }

    ……
   private void Button_ClickPlus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Text += '+';
    }

    ……
   private void Button_ClickDEv(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {      
        textBox.Text += '/';
    }

    private void Button_ClickEqual(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        object q = new DataTable().Compute(textBox.Text, null);
        textBox.Text = q.ToString();
    }

    private void Button_ClickReset(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       
        textBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: is there any DataTable function like "Compute" ablative in uwp? if so can you tell me how you get it?

Comment: @Abhishek Sharma I have tested it in uwp, and it works well. There are often some common methods that exist.

Comment: Can you tell me how you get it because I think I am missing something last time I tried adding it didn't work I have an app at a minimum and target platform set to the creator update no NuGet or any other reference and referenced to System.Data Namespace for DataTable

Comment: @Abhishek Sharma I just added the namespace "using System.Data". Maybe it is a problem with the target version. My target version is windows10 2004 (10.0, Build 19041), the minimum version is windows10 1809 (10.0, Build 17763).

Comment: I still have a problem because i need to be able to use an equation and using a name as a number, such as "Marcus = 42".

Comment: I got the 42 to work, but i dont know how to implement the equation.

Comment: @MrLowBot I don’t understand well what “F=m*a” means? Are ‘m’ and ‘a’ input number?

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT "M" and "A" are inputs, yes. F is the answers. The one of newtons equation for energy.

Comment: @MrLowBot The value of 'a' is about 9.8, which is a fixed value. Otherwise, it is no different from ordinary multiplication.
You can add the following code in the Button_Click_11 event:
         if (textBox.Text!="")
             {
                 textBox.Text += "*9.8";
                 textBox.Text = (new DataTable().Compute(textBox.Text, null)).ToString();
             }

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT "A" is not a fixed value. Youre thinking about "F = M*G".... "A" stands for the acceleration of an object and not gravity.

Comment: @MrLowBot You could implement it like a multiplication operation. The function of this button is no different from *.

Answer (score 0):

you have not reset the variable "input" that set's the data at equal click after copying that in y and after using input for x you are clearing "input" so the continuous calculation not working
you can install and Use "CoreCLR-NCalc" for uwp to calculate result directly from string and continuous calculation and directly build string by appending relative char